# Translate JFace buttons

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface, resourcebundle

I'm using an JFace Wizard dialog and I try to translate the four buttons at the bottom to German ... But whatever I try they're still named: Back, Next, Cancel and Finish.
All SWT dialogs were successfully adjusted to my operating system's language.
I already downloaded the respective language packages for JFace and included them in my eclipse classpath. At the moment it looks like this:

[image]

But no matter what settings I change the language of the wizard dialog remains unchanged. I also have already manually set the local setting of my application to German as following:

```
java.util.Locale.setDefault(java.util.Locale.GERMANY);
```

Eclipse Classpath:

[image]

But still the only things that are in German are my SWT Dialogs ...
Any ideas what else I could try out?

Comment: What does your classpath look like? Could you try to copy the `messages_de.properties` to a package `org.eclipe.jface` within your application project - just to see whether it is a 'packaging' problem or a locale issue?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann Ok I have added the German properties file directly into the JFace plugin and then it works just fine. 
I have added a screenshot from my classpath ... What do you think what the problem might be?

Comment: Is the screenshot showing *your* class-path or the *JFace* class-path? Besides, how do you run the application: as a plain Java application, as an OSGi application, or else?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann The screenshot is showing my class-path ... The JFace class-path is only the current plug-in, the dot only.
Currently we are running the application only within eclipse, but we are using maven to create a Java application.

Comment: The class-path screenshot seems to be from PDE's OSGi/Plug-in manifest editor. If you are using maven, you need to specify dependencies the maven way.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann No we don't need to define our dependencies in a POM file because we are using Tycho -> https://eclipse.org/tycho/

Comment: If you are writing an OSGi/Plug-in based application, the fragment shouldn't be put directly on a bundles' class-path. Just specify the fragment in the launch-configuration when running from within the IDE and in the feature/product for the Tycho build to include it.